# FileZilla and applescript

Tags: ftp, applescript, filezilla

I am making an applescript that converts a folder of flv and f4v files to mp4 files and then uploads the to a server via filezilla. How would I use applescript to upload to a server through Filezilla? Here is my code:

```
--Install handbrakecli into /usr/bin/

--on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
with timeout of (720 * 60) seconds
    tell application "Finder"
        --Get all flv and f4v files that have no label color yet, meaning it hasn't been processed

        set allFiles to every file of entire contents of ("Macintosh HD:Users:Chase:auto_convert:nope" as alias) whose ((name extension is "flv" or name extension is "f4v") and label index is 0)

        --Repeat for all files in above folder
        repeat with i from 1 to number of items in allFiles
            set currentFile to (item i of allFiles)

            try
                --label to indicate processing
                set label index of currentFile to 3

                --Assemble original and new file paths
                set origFilepath to quoted form of POSIX path of (currentFile as alias)
                set newFilepath to (characters 1 thru -5 of origFilepath as string) & "mp4'"

                --Start the conversion
                tell application "Terminal"
                    do shell script "HandBrakeCLI -i " & origFilepath & " -o " & newFilepath
                end tell
                --Set the label to red because this is the file that has been converted 
                set label index of currentFile to 6

                --Remove the old file
            on error errmsg
                --Set the label to red to indicate failure
                set label index of currentFile to 2
            end try
        end repeat

        set extensionToFind to "mp4"

        set topLevelFolder to "Macintosh HD:Users:Chase:auto_convert:nope" as text
        set pathCount to count of topLevelFolder

        set mp4Files to files of entire contents of folder topLevelFolder whose name extension is extensionToFind
        if mp4Files is {} then return

        set mp4Folder to "Macintosh HD:Users:Chase:auto_convert:yep"

        move mp4Files to mp4Folder


    end tell
end timeout
--end adding folder items to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a good idea, because Filezilla has no applescript support. I've always been surprised that Cyberduck doesn't either. But see:

http://discussions.apple.com/thread/2588937?start=0&tstart=0

.... on which there are good directions; curl in shell, or (at the end of the page) URL Access Scripting, which is a scripting addition that should be installed on your Mac. URL Access Scripting example:

```
tell application "URL Access Scripting"
upload filepathtoUpload to "ftp://username:password@domain.com/SOME/PATH/filename.jpg" replacing yes without binhexing
end tell
```